# Compiling only part of java classess to java script with GWT using module source path

Tags: module, gwt

Guys I am trying to filter out some java files to not be compiled to java script. I cant make it work. I've check documentation here:
https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml

> `<source path="_path_" />` : Each occurrence of the  tag adds a package to the source path by combining the package in which the module XML is found with the specified path to a subpackage. Any Java source file appearing in this subpackage or any of its subpackages is assumed to be translatable. The  element supports pattern-based filtering to allow fine-grained control over which resources get copied into the output directory during a GWT compile.
> If no  element is defined in a module XML file, the client subpackage is implicitly added to the source path as if  had been found in the XML. This default helps keep module XML compact for standard project layouts.

but still no success.

My module file: model.gwt.xml

located in: `com.company.section.app.model`

with content:

```
<module>
    <source path="">
    </source>
</module>
```

takes all java files from package:
`com.company.section.app.model`

And I would like to compile only few of them, from f.e.: package `com.company.section.app.model.to.javascript`

So I do change my module file content into:

```
<module>
    <source path="to.javascript">
    </source>
</module>
```

But I am getting errors, f.e.:

> [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 69: No source code is available for type
> com.company.section.app.model.to.javascript.DeviceDTO; did you forget to
> inherit a required module?

I've tried already many combinations like:

```
    <source path="com.company.section.app.model.to.javascript.*">
    <source path="to.javascript.*">
    <source path=".to.javascript.*">
```

Some times I am getting error:

```
[INFO] #
[INFO] # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
[INFO] #
[INFO] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f09897b3986, pid=1626892, tid=1626899
[INFO] #
[INFO] # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0.1+12) (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-121.04)
[INFO] # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-121.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
[INFO] # Problematic frame:
[INFO] # V  [libjvm.so+0x6db986]
[INFO] #
```

I added source plugin to the project I wanna import (model)

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also add source dependency to project

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

I can't find any good example of such usage. Do I miss some * asterix? I just dont get it.
Documentation stands that I should add part of package to path, or I miss understood.
Please help.

I hope I did explain it well enough.

Comment: The GWT transpiler tries to transpile your classes beneath 'to.javascript', but has no access to the source files. Did you add the source files inside your pom, so GWT can access them?

Comment: Yes I've added source plugin and I am importing source artifact to project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, or my mistake.
In xml module file we need to put path, and not package, like I was doing, so replacing:

```
<source path="to.javascript">
```

with

```
<source path="to/javascript">
```

Do the job